# Как подключить к кнопке элемент?

Tags: html, wordpress, css3

Как подключить к кнопке элемент? Делаю через visual composer, и надо чтобы элемент выезжал, по нажатию кнопки, но то что выезжает, это отдельный ряд, по сути, как подключить к колонке другой ряд?

Comment: что там у вас не получается ?

Comment: Я не понимаю, как в композере, связать между собой ряды, чтобы поставить кнопку в одной колонке, а при нажатии на неё, появлялся другой ряд

Comment: Делайте два ряда. Второй - изначально скрытый. Отрабатывайте нажатие на кнопку в js, присваивайте второму ряду класс, который открывает второй ряд и делает начальную анимацию (выезд). Это уже в css.

Comment: а что писать, чтобы по классу вызвало

Comment: так? document.getElementById('boxer').className = 'box';

Comment: просто тогда блок не выезжает, даже не появляется